# PowerShell ParametSets intellisense

Tags: powershell, parameters

Ever since I'm working with PowerShell I'm having difficulties to figure out how `ParameterSets` are supposed to be used properly. In the example below I would like to have `$OlderThan` and `$Quantity` both filled in if we one of them is addressed.

As you can see, this works just fine after some playing around:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,DefaultParameterSetName='A')]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='A')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='B')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [String]$Source,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1,ParameterSetName='A')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1,ParameterSetName='B')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [String]$Destination = $Source,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='A')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='B')]
    [ValidateSet('Year','Year\Month','Year-Month')]
    [String]$Structure = 'Year-Month',
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='B')]
    [ValidateSet('Day','Month','Year')]
    [String]$OlderThan,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='B')]
    [Int]$Quantity
)
```

`Get-Help` shows me the correct syntax that works fine:

```
SYNTAX
    S:\Test.ps1 [-Source] <String> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Structure <String>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

    S:\Test.ps1 [-Source] <String> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Structure <String>] -OlderThan <String> -Quantity <Int32> [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<Com
    monParameters>]
```

But what bothers me now (a little) is that when I type in the PowerShell ISE it's not automatically suggesting the parameters `OlderThan` and `Quantity` when I type the minus symbol (`-`).

For all other parameters it does display the names with intellisense. So when I want to use these 2 parameters I'm forced to remember their name and type it manually. Is this how it's supposed to work? 
Because when I try `DefaultParameterSetName='B'`, it is doing the intellisense correct on all parameters but it's also expecting me to fill in all the parameters, and that's not what I'm after.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this is actually a PowerShell bug.  Notice that if you type a single letter for the option (say -O) then type Ctrl+Space, it does show 'OlderThan'.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Ctrl+Space` combination. But you're right, it does come up when using this keyboard shortcut. So yes, it's probably a bug in the PowerShell ISE.

Comment: Bug reported at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/981521/intellisense-not-working-for-advanced-function-with-parametersetname)